# How to get node types in Electron with react typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, electron

## Here is the code

in React `App.tsx`

```
const fs = window.require('fs')
fs.readFile(....)
```

## Goal

1. Get node module types
2. Get node module intelliSense like fs.

## Problem

If I want to use node module inside electron React project, I shoud require 'fs' from window, but this would loose node module types and intelliSense

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeScript [import() types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-9-2/#import-types).

```js
const fs: typeof import("fs") = window.require('fs');
fs.readFile(...)
```

[image]